My player model is clipping through objects in Ursina when using FirstPersonController module
I am experimenting with ursina and am trying to create a player entity with a working collider and model. I have run into a problem, no matter how hard I try, the collider just won't work. I am trying to use the module to create a third person type camera system.
I have tried to use the mesh collider and box collider with the module to no avail. I have also tried creating a separate entity class and trying to add it to the FirstPersonController but alas it did not work either. I will post the images and code that I currently have.
This image depicts my model clipping halfway through my walls:

This image depicts my model clipping halfway through the floor:

This image depicts the collision detection on with my model clipping through the walls:

from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import *
from perlin_noise import PerlinNoise
noise = PerlinNoise(octaves=3, seed=random.randint(1,10000))
app = Ursina()

ground = Entity(
    model="cube",
    scale=(200,20,200),
    texture="grass",
    position=(0,-30,0),
    collider="box"
)
walls = Entity(
    model="walls_starting_area.obj",
    position=(0,-30,0),
    collider="mesh",
    texture="brick"
)

Sky()
class character(Entity):
    def __init__(self, position=(0,-20,0), model="cube", speed=20, collider="box",scale_x=1,scale_y=1):
        super().__init__(
            model=model,
            position=position,
            speed=speed,
            collider=collider,
            scale_x=scale_x,
            scale_y = scale_y
        )
        self.model = model
        self.position = position
        self.speed = speed
        self.collider = collider
        self.scale_x = scale_x
        self.scale_y = scale_y

wall = character(position=(0,-20,3), scale_x=30, scale_y=20,collider="box")
player = FirstPersonController(model="cube", collider="box",speed= 20)
camera.z = -5

def update():
    # Check for collisions between the player and other entities
    for obj in scene.entities:
        if obj.collider and player.intersects(obj).hit:
            print(f"Collision with {obj}")
app.run()

I have tried changing the origin of my model to y = 0.5 which does sort of fix the floor collision, but it only works on level floors, and it doesn't fix the walls.

I think that's because that collider (mesh) is used for more complicated objects,
so here's the code:
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import *
from perlin_noise import PerlinNoise
noise = PerlinNoise(octaves=3, seed=random.randint(1,10000))
app = Ursina()

ground = Entity(
    model="cube",
    scale=(200,20,200),
    texture="grass",
    position=(0,-30,0),
    collider="box"
)
walls = Entity(
    model="walls_starting_area.obj",
    position=(0,-30,0),
    collider="box", #changed the collider from mesh to "box"
    texture="brick"
)

Sky()
class character(Entity):
    def __init__(self, position=(0,-20,0), model="cube", speed=20, collider="box",scale_x=1,scale_y=1):
        super().__init__(
            model=model,
            position=position,
            speed=speed,
            collider=collider,
            scale_x=scale_x,
            scale_y = scale_y
        )
        self.model = model
        self.position = position
        self.speed = speed
        self.collider = collider
        self.scale_x = scale_x
        self.scale_y = scale_y

wall = character(position=(0,-20,3), scale_x=30, scale_y=20,collider="box")
player = FirstPersonController(model="cube", collider="box",speed= 20)
camera.z = -5

def update():
    # Check for collisions between the player and other entities
    for obj in scene.entities:
        if obj.collider and player.intersects(obj).hit:
            print(f"Collision with {obj}")
app.run()

#i have test the code btw

